# Merging two hashes by concatenating the arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.9

Given two hashes whose values are arrays, what is the best way to merge them so that when the two shares some key, the resulting value will be the concatenation of the values of the original two hashes? For example, given two hashes `h1` and `h2`:

```
h1 = Hash.new{[]}.merge(a: [1], b: [2, 3])
h2 = Hash.new{[]}.merge(b: [4], c: [5])
```

I expect that the method `convolute` will give:

```
h1.convolute(h2) #=> {:a => [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [5]}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is exactly what `Hash#merge` does if you give it a block:

```
h1.merge(h2) do |key, v1, v2|
  v1 + v2
end
```

http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Hash:merge

Comment: +1. Maybe `<<` in stead of `+` is even better, not creating  a new array.

Comment: @steenslag But both v1 and v2 are arrays.

Comment: @sawa Yes, but v1 + v2 creates a new (third) array. << keeps the total at two. Same thing with strings btw.

Comment: I think you mean `v1.concat(v2)`, `v1 << v2` would add `v2` as the last element of `v1`, not concatenate. In other words `v1 + v2` and `v1.concat(v2)` are equivalent except that the latter mutates `v1`, whereas `v1 << v2` would give you something like `[2, 3, [4]]` in the case of the `b` key from the example in the question. I assumed, however, the OP didn't want to mutate his/her datastructures. There's definitely a place for optimizations like not creating extra unnecessary objects, but it's also a common source for bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about modifying `h2` then:

```
h1.each_with_object(h2) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
```

If you want to leave `h2` alone:

```
h1.each_with_object(h2.dup) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
```

And if you want that specific order:

```
h2.each_with_object(h1.dup) { |(k, v), h| h[k] += v }
```

Comment: The third one is the one. Thanks.